# Did Allah Already Decide Somebody will be on Hell before He/She Was Even Created?

Tags: death, jahannam, qadar, suicide

**(1).The People Committing Suicide in Hell.**

> - "He gives life and causes death, and to Him you will be    returned."**(Surat Yūnus,verse56)**

- "... When Abraham said, "My Lord is the one who gives life and causes    death" ..."**(Surat Al-Baqarah, verse 258)**
- "But whoever kills a believer intentionally - his recompense is Hell,
  wherein he will abide eternally, and Allah has become angry with him
  and has cursed him and has prepared for him a great
  punishment."**(Surat An-Nisā', verse 93)**
- "...if anyone slew a person - unless it be for murder or for
  spreading mischief in the land - it would be as if he slew the whole
  people: and if anyone saved a life, it would be as if he saved the
  life of the whole people..."**(Surat Al-Mā'idah, verse 32)**

**(2). The God Has Already Decided One's Death (How and When), Even Before He/She Was Born in this World**

When you combine these two points you will get The God has already decided who will be in hell before He/She is even Born.

This actually is a question asked by a friend of mine, but I'm clueless. Can Anybody Give Me Any Explanations, Instead of just Down-voting.?

Comment: the down voters please comment..."why you are down voted ?".then i can improve my question

Comment: it's very bad that you are down voting when you are stuck...like feared people.

Answer (score -1):

**In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Merciful**

---

**Your question:** Did God decided where the person will go before he was created?

**Answer:**

No, He didn’t decided our fates because God says (interpretation of the meaning):

> ”And I (God) created not the jinn and mankind except that they should worship Me (Alone)”
>   **[al-Dhaariyaat 51:56].**
>
> ”And to God belongs all that is in the heavens and all that is in the earth, that He may requite those who do evil with that which they have done (i.e. punish them in Hell), and reward those who do good, with what is best (i.e. Paradise)”
>   [al-Najm 5 :31]

God didn’t decided our fates before we were created, He created us and gave us the opportunity to choose where we wanna go, but He knows where we’re going. He created us so that we can be tested, and He is the one who decides where one goes according to person’s deeds and belief. He decided To Create everything including us without deciding where we will go. This life is a test, remember that. And He is the law maker.

Fore more informations, I invite you to check the following videos:

1. [**If Allah Knows Everything Where is the Test?**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaO1XZKqfVg)
2. [**If Allah knows the future why does he test us - Mufti Menk**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaO1XZKqfVg)